# Intellij - conflicting module versions - how to find source of dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, groovy

I have a groovy class in maven java project. I upgraded the groovy dependency from 2.4.4. to 2.4.11. If I build the project using maven - it works. However, if I build it with IntelliJ - I get this error:

```
Information:Groovyc: While compiling MyProject: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-jsr223 is loaded in version 2.4.11 and you are trying to load version 2.4.4
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.
```

When I go to project structre -> dependencies, I see: Maven: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-jsr233:2.4.4.
When I search all my pom.xml fiels for 2.4.4 - there is nothing left - everywhere I have 2.4.11.

I tried rebuilding all with maven, reimporting maven projects in IntelliJ - nothing works.

Where should I look for this dependency? Is there a quick way to track it?

Comment: Try to delete `.idea` directory and `*.iml` files, then reimport from `pom.xml`. If it doesn't help, file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the logs and a small sample project to reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution - Maven Helper plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper). It adds "Dependency Analyzer" tab to pom files view.

Answer (score 1):

Many time this trick works for me.

go to maven widget in intellij idea and click on the refresh icon. it should do the magic.

[image]

Comment: Thank, you, I've tried it (this reimports all maven projects) - but the problem still exists.